# WinAPIServer::crypt(Un)ProtectData error on AOS-Cluster

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Using the functions `WinAPIServer::cryptProtectData()` and `WinAPServer::cryptUnprotectData()` to store passwords in the database worked fine for a while.

Using this technique on an AOS-Cluster doesn't.
Code stops execution on `WinAPIServer::cryptUnprotectData()` without any error-message.

Decrypting only works on the AOS where the Crpyting has been done. 
Retyping and crypting the password on AOS 2 ( where uncrypting doesn't work at this time ) leads to the fact that AOS 2 can uncrpyt, but AOS 1 not and vice versa. I found [some infos](http://steevegilbert.ca/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=10&Itemid=10) regarding problems after changing password of the AOS-User, but the AOS-User is the same on both AOS-instances. So is the password. Are there any further unique IDs or something involved in crypting/uncrypting?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/winapiserver.aspx) doesn't give me any helpful information...

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at how the password for the SMTP server in AX is stored. Also take a look at [Why does table SysEmailSMTPPassword save the SMTP password per AOS instance?](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/47917.aspx) It seems the encryption depends on a windows registry value, which makes it dependent on the AOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On the linked resource, the thesis about the dependency between AOS-user/password and encryption is underlined. But as I mentioned in OP, the AOS-user/password is **identical** on both AOS. So I think, there's any other influence?!

Comment: Although the AOS-user and password are the same, the encryption key is probably different?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to know for sure - not guessed ;)